# Django cannot save blank value in FloatField

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a simple model in Django:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.FloatField(default=0.0, blank=True)
```

In my views.py, I am fetching user input from a page. The html code is:

```
<form action="{% url 'test' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="number" placeholder="Test" class="form-control mb-2" name="test">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

The views.py code is:

```
name = request.POST.get('test', '0.0')      #I have tried without the '0.0' as well.
        new_test = Test(name=name)
        new_test.save()
```

I keep getting the error:

```
ValueError at /test 
Field 'name' expected a number but got ''.
```

How can I make django save a blank value or '0.0'(default value) or a null value when the user enters nothing. It seems to accept none of these.

Comment: Why don't you simply use a [`Form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/) class, it will do such validation / cleaning etc. automatically.

Comment: This is the way harvard's cs50web taught me. I will look into using the Form class, but there should be a way for this to work as well.

Comment: The `get` transformation will only work if there is no `'test'`  key in the `POST` dict. Either create a default value in the form input or test `name` in the code , something like `if not name: name = 0`. The issue is that Postgres will not take an empty string '' as a number value.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Ok, that makes sense. But even as it is, I am getting a value of ''(which is equal to blank if I am not mistaken, correct me if I am wrong). Shouldn't the blank=True parameter allow for saving a '' value?

Comment: Read this [Blank](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#blank). Difference between form and database values.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I think I'll just manually validate the input. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why not just set a default in the form field, [Input number](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_number.asp)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your field `name` is a `FloatField` hence it expects numbers, hence when an empty string (`''`) is passed to it you get an error. `request.POST.get('test', '0.0')` does not work because when the user submits the field leaving it blank the fields value is kept as an empty string, meaning the key is present in `request.POST` but it's value is `''`.

Normally if one would have used a [`Form` class [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/) or a `ModelForm` class, these values would have been cleaned automatically by the form and would have been replaced by `None`. I would advice you to use the form classes. If you still insist on doing things manually you would go about cleaning the value somewhat like this:

```
from django.core import validators


name = request.POST.get('test', '0.0')
if name in validators.EMPTY_VALUES: # if name in (None, '', [], (), {})
    name = None
else:
    name = float(name) # Might still get error here, if receiving non-numeric input
new_test = Test(name=name)
new_test.save()
```

**Note**: This is just a very small part of cleaning and validation, there are more errors that can occur here, example a user enters a non-numeric input into the field, etc. I would advice using form classes.

Comment: I see. I guess I'll manually validate the input. And in the longer run, learn to use the form class

Answer (score 1):

You have to use something like this:

```
name = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0.0)
```

Comment: If you put some number like 11.22, does it work correctly?

Comment: it works. Problem is when user doesn't enter anything